# Permalinks with custom post type in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to create a new custom type named "projects" but my permalinks don't work.
This is my code :

```
function register_post_types() {
        $labels = array(
                    ...
                );

        $args = array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'public' => true,
                        'has_archive' => false,
                        'rewrite' => array('with_front' => false, 'feeds' => false, 'pages' => false),
                        'supports' => array(
                            'title',
                            'editor',
                            'thumbnail',
                            'excerpt',
                            'comments'
                            )
                );

        register_post_type( 'projects', $args);
```

I get a 404 with the url http://website.com/projects/my-project even by manually changing the permalinks (Post name => Numeric => Post name).

When debug (I use the Dev4press trick : http://www.dev4press.com/2012/tutorials/wordpress/practical/debug-wordpress-rewrite-rules-matching/) here are my results :

```
<!-- Request: projects/my-project -->
<!-- Matched Rewrite Rule: projects/([^/]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$ -->
<!-- Matched Rewrite Query: projects=my-project&amp;page= -->
<!-- Loaded Template: 404.php -->
```

Can you help me please ?

**Edit :**
Strangely if I replace

```
'rewrite' => array('with_front' => false, 'feeds' => false, 'pages' => false)
```

with

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'p', 'with_front' => false, 'feeds' => false, 'pages' => false)
```

I can access to http://website.com/p/my-project/, but if I change the slug with 'projects' I can't access to http://website.com/projects/my-project/ :(

Answer (score 0):

go to Settings > Permalinks in the admin panel. click on save button. and see what will happen.....

Comment: Thank you Kashif, unfortunately I record my rewrite rules whenever I modify my source code with the flush rewrite rules() function and I've got the same problem.